# ssh keys for multiple accounts on one host

Tags: ssh-keys

I have two accounts on a linux server and would like to have an ssh key for both of them. Do I need to make two keys, so that I can both `ssh user1@server.url` and `ssh user2@server.url` without needing to enter a password? Everything I've read seems to indicate you reuse your key without issue but it also seems like this server is complaining that the key already exists there; that makes me assume I do in fact need two keys, but want to confirm.

Comment: Which part of "this server" is showing you those complaints?

Comment: "Do I need to make two keys" - Using separated keys, for different users, is best practice. If you were talking about the same individual, on separate users, an argument might be made for using the same key.  You wouldn't be able to use the same identical file, you could use the same key, but different files due to the permission rules on those keys.